# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath slow to update

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my iOS app, I have an `UITableView` with prototyped cells. Each `cell` displays a message of text and has a `label` for displaying the number of comments associated with that message. Currently, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm querying the server for an `array` that holds the comments associated with the message, then setting the `label` to `array.count`. However, while scrolling through the `table`, this causes split-second inaccuracies in the comment count because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has to query the server each time a new `cell` comes on screen, so sometimes the `label` will temporarily display the comment count of another message (the old prototyped cell) while the new comment count is still loading. What's the best solution to this problem?

Comment: The worst thing you can do in `cellForRow...` is to make a network call. What happens to users with no connection, or worse, a really slow connection? You need to load the data once, in the background. Kick it off in `viewDidLoad`. Then reload the table when you have the data.

Comment: So are you saying in viewDidLoad I should query the server for the # of comments for each message displayed in the table, then store that information locally, then have the cells reference this local information?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what you want.

Comment: put code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Hmm...so if I have 100 cells in the table, that means I should create 100 local arrays of those cell's corresponding comments? This sounds quite inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make server requests in the background in the table view, do it by importing `dispatch/dispatch.h` and then using this code

```
//in the cellForRowAtIndexPath; method
dispatch_queue_t bg = dispatch_queue_create("com.you.test", NULL);
dispatch_async(bg, ^{
    //get stuff from server
});
```